# Core Data: Inherited entities

Tags: ios, core-data, inheritance

What is the proper way of storing inherited entities in Core Data?
Let's say I have a Shape entity which (is|can be) abstract and corresponding Shape class.
There are sub-entities/subclasses of Shape: Circle, Rectangle, Triangle.

I will need to put all my shapes in UITableView (may be in different sections or even not).

How should I store all these shapes?

1. As Shape entities and then cast them to concrete Shape subclass after fetching and before adding to datasource array
2. As concrete shape entities and then fetch and join them all in one array as datasource for UITableView

I don't think the first way is even possible...

May be there is some other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare shape as an abstract entity, and declare your Circle and others as sub entity of Shape. When you are performing a fetch, you can use setIncludesSubentities: on your NSFetchRequest object to fetch the Shape and all sub entities (if this is what you want to do, having them on one array).

Comment: Some people are discouraging from this because of performance problems